# Consume a C# API that returns file or byte[] from javascript as image

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, angular, asp.net-web-api

I've the following code that returns an image in C# Web API. So far so good but I can't map it to an image.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("GetImage")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public FileResult GetImage(string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) {
            return File("imgs/nodisponible.jpg", "image/jpg");
        }
        var imagen = REST.GetImage(name);
        return new FileContentResult(imagen, "image/jpeg");
    }
```

So on the javascript side I made:

```
  getimage(word: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<ArrayBuffer>(this.baseUrl + 'library/getimage', word, {
      headers: this.headers,
      withCredentials: true,
    });
  }
```

and then to show the image:

```
 const iname = JSON.stringify(this.consultadetalle?.cover_url);
  this.dataService.getimage(iname).subscribe((responses) => {
    $('#imagencover').attr('src', "data:image/png;base64," + responses);
  });
```

but the console says:

> Http failure during parsing for
> https://localhost:44476/library/getimage"

How can I solve this?

Update:
As I said, I'm using Web API, I don't have the view in C#, only javascript with angular. In C# I've only the controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to convert the file to bytes first. I successfully used this, in a project similar to yours, to convert the image file to a byte array.

```
public static byte[] ConverToBytes(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var length = file.InputStream.Length; //Length: 103050706
    byte[] fileData = null;
    using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
    {
        fileData = binaryReader.Renter code hereeadBytes(file.ContentLength);
    }
    return fileData;
}
```

after which I loaded that information into a Viewbag and converted that to Base64

```
var ImageBytes = ConverToBytes(ImageFromApi);         
var displayImage= "data:" + imagePulled.FileType + ";base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(ImageBytes);
                ViewBag.FileBytes = displayImage;
```

then displayed it in a view using this.

```
<object data="@ViewBag.FileBytes" id="imageDisplayFrame" style="width:100%; min-height:600px; border:1px solid lightgrey; object-fit:contain;" #zoom="200" frameBorder="1" type="@ViewBag.FileType" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not using Razor, from .NET is only a Web API. The View is made by angular in javascript.

Comment: Oh, got it. This error looked familiar to me when I was working on this project. You may only need to convert the image file to a byte array then base 64 before attempting to pass it into the src attribute.

Comment: Oh, ok! So let me thing then in do what you do in tobase64string

Comment: yes, was that. The action now returns a string that it comes from Tobase64string conversion and then with javascript just only concatenate to data:. Nice

Comment: I was stumped on the same error for a couple of days. Glad this worked for you. Good luck with your project.